# gmap-api circle warning: A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have more than 120 markers on google maps and want to bind 2 circles to each marker.
I have achieved this but I keep on getting the warning :-

" Stop running this script ? A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly.If it continues to run,your computer might become unresponsive" on IE.

I get this error only for circle overlays.

How shall I fix this? What are the ways to optimise ?

Below is the example. Locations are not the exact ones I am using , but this is how I have implemented in my application

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.4&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>

var cityLoacations = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782919, -122.442815),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782992, -122.442112),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783100, -122.441461),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783206, -122.440829),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783273, -122.440324),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783316, -122.440023),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783371, -122.439687),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783368, -122.439666),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783383, -122.439594),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783508, -122.439525),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783842, -122.439591),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.784147, -122.439668),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.784206, -122.439686),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.784386, -122.439790),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.784701, -122.439902),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.784965, -122.439938),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785010, -122.439947),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785360, -122.439952),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785715, -122.440030),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786117, -122.440119),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786564, -122.440209),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786905, -122.440270),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786956, -122.440279),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800224, -122.433520),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800155, -122.434101),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800160, -122.434430),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800378, -122.434527),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800738, -122.434598),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800938, -122.434650),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.801024, -122.434889),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800955, -122.435392),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800886, -122.435959),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800811, -122.436275),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800788, -122.436299),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800719, -122.436302),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800702, -122.436298),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800661, -122.436273),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800395, -122.436172),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800228, -122.436116),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800169, -122.436130),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.800066, -122.436167),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.784345, -122.422922),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.784389, -122.422926),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.784437, -122.422924),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.784746, -122.422818),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785436, -122.422959),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786120, -122.423112),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786433, -122.423029),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786631, -122.421213),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786660, -122.421033),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786801, -122.420141),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786823, -122.420034),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786831, -122.419916),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.787034, -122.418208),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.787056, -122.418034),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.787169, -122.417145),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.787217, -122.416715),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786144, -122.416403),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785292, -122.416257),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.780666, -122.390374),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.780501, -122.391281),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.780148, -122.392052),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.780173, -122.391148),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.780693, -122.390592),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.781261, -122.391142),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.781808, -122.391730),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782340, -122.392341),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782812, -122.393022),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783300, -122.393672),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783809, -122.394275),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.784246, -122.394979),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.784791, -122.395958),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785675, -122.396746),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786262, -122.395780),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.786776, -122.395093),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.787282, -122.394426),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.787783, -122.393767),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.788343, -122.393184),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.788895, -122.392506),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.789371, -122.391701),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.789722, -122.390952),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.790315, -122.390305),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.790738, -122.389616),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.779448, -122.438702),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.779023, -122.438585),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.778542, -122.438492),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.778100, -122.438411),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.777986, -122.438376),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.777680, -122.438313),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.777316, -122.438273),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.777135, -122.438254),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776987, -122.438303),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776946, -122.438404),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776944, -122.438467),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776892, -122.438459),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776842, -122.438442),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776822, -122.438391),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776814, -122.438412),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776787, -122.438628),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776729, -122.438650),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776759, -122.438677),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776772, -122.438498),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776787, -122.438389),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776848, -122.438283),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.776870, -122.438239),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.777015, -122.438198),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.777333, -122.438256),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.777595, -122.438308),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.777797, -122.438344),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.778160, -122.438442),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.778414, -122.438508),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.778445, -122.438516),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.778503, -122.438529),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.778607, -122.438549),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.778670, -122.438644),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.778847, -122.438706),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.779240, -122.438744)
];

var cityOuterCircle , cityInnerCircle;

function addMarkers() {
        for (var city in cityLoacations) {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(city[0],city[1]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng
                });
                marker.setMap(map);
        }
}
function addCircle() {
        for (var city in cityLoacations) {
            var outerCircleOptions = {
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              fillColor: '#F781F3',
              fillOpacity: 0.35,
              map: map,
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(city[0],city[1]),
             radius: 120701
            };

            var innerCircleOptions = {
                      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                      strokeWeight: 2,
                      fillColor: '#F4FA58',
                      fillOpacity: 0.35,
                      map: map,
                     center: new google.maps.LatLng(city[0],city[1]),
                     radius: 241402
                    };

            cityOuterCircle = new google.maps.Circle(outerCircleOptions);
            cityInnerCircle = new google.maps.Circle(innerCircleOptions);
          }
}

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

  addMarkers();
  addCircle();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Comment: It'd help if you share some code?

Comment: For which purposes do yo need the circles?

Comment: I have hundreds of stores in each country and I want to display the store under which the customer's location falls. If it doesn't fall under any store then display the nearest store. Could you please suggest any solution to display all the stores(markers) and range(circles) as mentioned in my question?

Comment: @Dr.Molle Sir,please could you help? Will buying a license help me ?

Comment: Buying a licence will make no difference, the performance degradation is on the clients machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not an error per se, the code is running as intended, the browser is simply warning you that it will take a large amount of time and considering you're asking the client side to render 120 markers and 240 circles I would say this is to be expected. You will have to look into optimisation or perhaps redesign you're ui in order to
To circumvent this.

The simplest Google maps optimisation is always implementing a marker clusterer, examples available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers).

Alternatively you might want to look at redesigning the functionality and adding filters to the markers? Is is necessary to display all of the points at once?

Comment: I have already tried MarkerCluster but still I get the same warning.It is necessary to display all the points and the circles. I need the ways to optimise.

Comment: I don't think optimisation of the circle drawing section of the Ali is possible, unless you're willing to render the points yourself using a canvas or svg based solution?

Comment: Please could you give me an example for having so many circle overlays using a canvas?

Comment: I don't know of an example unfortunately, that's why I said it'd have to be something you'd write yourself (sorry if I didn't make that clear). Drawing that many circles is just something the maps api was unfortunately not designed for. Did you try and implement a marker clusterer to reduce load?